# Why do subprocesses import the main module at start on Windows while they don't on Linux?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, porting

Example: the following code runs fine on Ubuntu 14.04

```
# some imports
import numpy as np
import glob
import sys
import multiprocessing
import os

# creating some temporary data
tmp_dir = os.path.join('tmp', 'nptest')
if not os.path.exists(tmp_dir):
    os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
    for i in range(10):
        x = np.random.rand(100, 50)
        y = np.random.rand(200, 20)
        file_path = os.path.join(tmp_dir, '%05d.npz' % i)
        np.savez_compressed(file_path, x=x, y=y)

def read_npz(path):
    data = dict(np.load(path))
    return (data['x'], data['y'])

def parallel_read(files):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    data_list = pool.map(read_npz, files)
    return data_list

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dir, '*.npz'))
x = parallel_read(files)
print('done')
```

but fails on Windows 7, with an error message along the lines of:

```
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 159, in __init__
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 223, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in __init__
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

From my understanding, this stems from the fact that subprocesses import the main module at start on Windows while they don't on Linux. The issue on Windows can be prevented by placing `x = parallel_read(files)` in a main function. E.g.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    x = parallel_read(files)
    print('done')
```

Why do subprocesses import the main module at start on Windows while they don't on Linux?

Comment: Because Linux has `fork` to start new processes with a copy of the current process's state, and Windows does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't have a `fork` function. Most other OSs do, and on those platforms it is used by `multiprocessing` to launch the new processes with the same state as the parent process. Windows has to set up the state of the child process by other means, including importing the `__main__` module.

Note that Python 3.4 (and later) lets you use the non-forking implementation on all operating systems, if you request it. See [issue 8713](https://bugs.python.org/issue8713) on the bug tracker for the discussion of this feature.